# How to pass a variable as a string into HTML without the last 4 characters

Tags: python, html, flask, variables

I am trying to display images on my website using flask. I have a for loop that iterates over the images found on my 'static' directory but I also want to dispplay the names of the images at the bottom of the image. At the moment the images' names are appearing as 'image.jpg' but I wish to get rid of the '.jpg'. Any idea how I can do this?

Here is my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, url_for
import os

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/select.html')
def select():
  imagelist = os.listdir(os.path.join(app.static_folder,"images"))
  return render_template("select.html", imagelist=imagelist)
  
@app.route('/versus.html')
def versus():
  return render_template("versus.html")
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

Here is the html template in which I have the for loop

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Disney Favorites</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      .center {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 50%;
      }
      .centre {
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1 style= "font-size: 25px" class="text-center">Click on your favorite animated Disney canon movie</h1>
      <section>
        {% for image in imagelist %}
        <div class="centre">
          <button type="submit">
          <img class="center" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + image) }}">
          </img>
          <p>{{image}}</p>
          </button>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </section>
```

Comment: Does `image.replace(".jpg", "")` work inside the html or does this throw an error?

Comment: @Lenntror That is not removing the last four characters, that is replacing `.jpg` _anywhere_ in `image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use a filter:

```
<p>{{image|replace(".jpg", "")}}</p>
```

Comment: Thats replacing one string within another string, and only coincidently removing it if it is at the end.

Comment: @BlackJack And if your images are `.tiff` or `.webp` files just ditching the last 4 characters  will get the wrong output, and if the images are not stored on the server but generated and have no extension as a URL, but type is part of the response, always removing 4 characters is wrong

Comment: That's why the better solution is to use `pathlib.Path` to get the filename without the extension.  Also solves the problem that the code in the question joins path and filename with a hard coded separator and `+`.

Answer (score 0):

That is kind of a lazy question.  String is a basic data type and removing a fixed number of characters with string slicing (`filename[:-4]`) and the [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) like `filename.remove_suffix(".jpg")` are usually part of beginners tutorials or at least easy to discover by looking through the documentation.

This isn't even Flask or web programming related:

```py
>>> import jinja2
>>> jinja2.Template("{{filename[:-4]}}").render(filename="test.jpg")
'test'
```

Comment: it is Flask because Jinja2 is the default template engine for Flask

Comment: if the template engine does not support your proposed constructs you have a problem

Comment: @rioV8 But that's irrelevant, the question is about the Python `str` type.  That doesn't change its API or behaviour in a web app or Jinja templates.

Comment: A better solution would be to ditch plain strings for paths and use `pahtlib.Path` from the standard library and the `stem` attribute for getting the filename without extension.

Comment: so if I read a text file in my Python script all expressions are evaluated? `{{x|y}}` is not a valid Python construct but it does something useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method **slice** with a negative number to start counting from the end of the string.

```
image = "myImage.jpg"
pureImageName = image[:-4]
    
print(pureImageName) // myImage
```

Comment: the OP needs the solution in the Jinja2 template, he needs the filename and the filename without possible extension